# Unable to create a Div that Fits to the text size

Tags: html, css, center, fits

I'm unable to get a div to fit the size of the text inside of it.

I have 2 divs, and I want the inner div to:

**1.** Fit inside the outer div.

**2.** Be centered inside the wrapping div.

The problem I am experiencing is that when I play around with the width of the view, I am getting a large unwanted gap between the text and the div's border, as you can see here:
[image]

Can you see the large gap on the right? I want it to be as small as the one on the left side.

How can I prevent this gap, and furthermore, how can I make the div center inside the large div to make its size big enough to fit the text inside of it?

Here is my fiddle test: https://jsfiddle.net/gv1xLd8s

**My code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="divForText">
Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... 
VeryLongWordToCheckTheGapProblemOnLeftAndRightSides
Text...  Text...
</div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.divForText{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Hope that my question is understood.

1. Using "word-break: break-all" is not a solution because I don't want to break words in the middle.
2. I want to accomplish this using pure HTML and CSS, No JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use width:50%?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have width limit then you can remove the width limit i.e. 50% from the wrapper class.
Then the CSS will be

```
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Hope it will work.Good luck

Comment: It's Not working, the gap on the right side is still there as I showed in the picture in my original post. I really don't understand why people don't try to check their solutions before they are posting them here, it takes less than 20 seconds to check it in the fiddle.

Comment: i have tested it in the fiddle that u have given. check this https://jsfiddle.net/n1zk809y/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is happening because of the long word with no-spaces so the browser cannot break it and it's not fitting with the rest of line so it's going to the new line leaving a big space behind.

to solve this issue you can use this css

```
.divForText{
  ...
  hyphens: auto;
  ...
}
```

the browser will add a hyphen automatically when it's needed.

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.divForText{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="divForText">
Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... VeryLongWordToCheckTheGapProblemOnLeftAndRightSides Text...  Text...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's Not working, the gap on the right side is still there as I showed in the picture in my original post. I really don't understand why people don't try to check their solutions before they are posting them here. It takes less than 20 seconds to check it in the fiddle site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could solve your problem.

```
.wrapper{
border: 1px solid blue;
text-align: center;
padding: 25px;
margin: auto;
width: 77%;
}
.divForText{
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It's Not working, the gap on the right side is still there as I showed in the picture in my original post. I really don't understand why people don't try to check their solutions before they are posting them here. It takes less than 20 seconds to check it in the fiddle site.

Comment: I think this is not a good way to treat  people who wanna help ya.

Comment: It has been tested on my pc. check in this links and try to be kind.  https://jsfiddle.net/5bgov0zk/